# The set of configurations reachable from an initial configuration is a lattice -- nonconvergent/ infinite chip-firing games

Tags: combinatorics

The support graph $G$ is taken to be finite, simple, and connected.

Given an initial configuration $\mathbf{c}_0$, I would like to show that the set of configurations reachable from $\mathbf{c}_0$ forms a lattice under $\mathbf{a} \leq \mathbf{b}$ iff $\mathbf{b}$ is reachable from $\mathbf{a}$. (Klivans exercise 2.8.18)

Joins for convergent CFGs are not too bad, as are meets in general. I am not certain, though, about nonconvergent chip-firing games. Taking $\mathbf{c}_1$ and $\mathbf{c}_2$, it seems that there could be two possible "loops" -- if you will -- of configurations reachable corresponding to $\mathbf{c}_1$ and $\mathbf{c}_2$, but I am failing to construct such a case.

The "inverse question" -- why must two non-convergent/ infinite chip-firing sequences eventually reach the same configuration?

Comment: I am not at all expert in this domain, but do you know this amazing book: https://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Chip-Firing-Discrete-Its-Applications/dp/1138634093

Comment: Yep... in fact, that's where I got this problem haha. @JeanMarie